# Regarding the intersection of prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I \vartriangleleft R$ be an ideal.
>
> Show that if $I = p_1 \cap \ldots \cap p_r = q_1 \cap \ldots \cap q_s$, where the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are prime ideals in $R$ with $p_i \not \subset p_j$ and $q_k \not \subset q_l$ for all $i \ne j \in [1,r]$ and all $k \ne l \in [1,l]$, then $\{p_1,\ldots,p_r\} = \{q_1,\ldots,q_s\}$.

I do not see how I could prove this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p_1\cap(p_2\cap\dots\cap p_r)=q_1\cap\dots\cap q_s$, it follows that $p_1\supseteq (q_1\cap\dots\cap q_s)$. From this it follows that $p_1\supseteq q_i$ for some $i$. By contradiction, suppose that $p_1\not\supseteq q_i$ for all $i$, then for each $i$ there is an element $x_i\in q_i$ with $x_i\not \in p_1$. Then $\prod_i x_i\in q_1\cap\dots\cap q_s$ but $\prod_i x_i\not \in p_1$ (because $p_1$ is prime). Then $p_1\not\supseteq q_1\cap\dots \cap q_s$, which is a contradiction. Without loss of generality $p_1\supseteq q_1$, proceed by induction and you will conclude your result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want to point out that there is a small typo in line 2, it should be $p_1 \not \supseteq q_i$. I can not edit this however.